# SQL Server : filling temporary table with supplementary data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I currently have the following result set:

```
WEEKDAY     INITIAL_MIN       ENDING_MIN
----------- ----------------- -----------------
7           0                 150 
7           360               480
7           980               1310
6           200               300
```

This data got the week day (from 1 to 7) and unavailable working time (in minutes, so 0 is 00:00 and 1439 is 23:59) and **I can't change its format/data type due to database restrictions**.

I need to insert the supplemental data for each weekday on another table, so in this example it would be:

```
WEEKDAY     INITIAL_MIN       ENDING_MIN
----------- ----------------- -----------------
7           151               359
7           481               979
7           1311              1439
6           0                 199
6           301               1439
5           0                 1439
4           0                 1439
3           0                 1439
2           0                 1439
1           0                 1439
```

The restrictions I've got:

- That's a SQL Server 2005 database
- I can't create TV/Scalar functions (just procedures)

Comment: 1339 is 23:59. How do you derive that? Or did you mean 1439, give that a day has 1440 minutes?

Comment: Sorry raj, misstype + copy/paste :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution (assume your initial result set is @tmp):

First I have to set up the result set ready for my final `SELECT`:

Where ever the first record of the day does not start at 0 I add a placeholder record with INITIAL_MIN = -1, ENDING_MIN = -1. My final select will now find the range between the placeholders and the first row of the day.

```
INSERT INTO @tmp
SELECT WEEKDAY, -1, -1
FROM @tmp 
WHERE WEEKDAY NOT IN (SELECT WEEKDAY FROM @tmp WHERE INITIAL_MIN <= 0)
```

The next query works out all the missing time ranges - it stores them in a temporary table so this must be dropped first if it already exists.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#result') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #result

SELECT t1.WEEKDAY
    ,INITIAL_MIN = ISNULL(t1.ENDING_MIN+1, 0)
    ,ENDING_MIN = ISNULL(t2.INITIAL_MIN-1, 1439)
INTO #result
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WEEKDAY ORDER BY INITIAL_MIN DESC) 
    FROM @tmp t
    WHERE ENDING_MIN < 1439
) t1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
        ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WEEKDAY ORDER BY INITIAL_MIN DESC) 
    FROM @tmp t
) t2 ON t1.WEEKDAY = t2.WEEKDAY AND t2.rn = t1.rn-1
ORDER BY WEEKDAY, INITIAL_MIN
```

Add the days that weren't in the original results at all:

```
DECLARE @wkday TINYINT = 1
WHILE @wkday <= 7
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tmp WHERE WEEKDAY = @wkday)
    INSERT INTO #result 
    VALUES( @wkday, 0, 1439)

    SET @wkday = @wkday + 1
END
```

Finally just SELECT the data from the temporary table

```
SELECT * FROM #result
```

OUTPUT:

```
WEEKDAY INITIAL_MIN ENDING_MIN
------- ----------- -----------
1       0           1439
2       0           1439
3       0           1439
4       0           1439
5       0           1439
6       0           199
6       301         1439
7       151         359
7       481         979
7       1311        1439
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to avoid the "There is already an object named '#tmp' in the database." error when selecting into a temporary table twice.

Comment: Actually I'm having the trouble to generate the supplementary data itself.

Comment: Updated. Give that a try

Comment: OGHaza, thanks a lot! It's basically working except i just need the supplementary values (not the older ones). 
Is there a easy way to remove then or its just better to use a NOT IN clause pointing to the original table)

Comment: Ok answer updated. I've shuffled around the order things are done a bit.